# Height 100% of Div inside 100% container?

Tags: html, css

```
<div id="container">

   <div id="content">
   //my content
   </div>

</div>

#container{
 height:100%!important;
 min-height:700px!important;
}
#content{
 height:100%!important;
}
```

I have a container div with a content div inside, no matter what I do, I can't get the content div to be the same height as the container div. Am I missing something?

Thanks

Comment: Just to be clear your CSS is in a style section at the top and the divs are in the body and it's not in the HTML as you show here?

Answer (score 0):

Add `height:100%` to html and body

```
html, body{height:100%}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vqjYu/1/)**

---

you can add min-height:700px (or inherit) to child div also. I hope it does the trick.

[**UPDATED DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/vqjYu/2/)

Add more content to the inner div to check the `height:100%` effect when content increases.

Comment: Your demo does not include  min-height:700px!important;

Comment: In that case you can add min-height:700px (or inherit) to child div also. I hope it does the trick. I have updated the fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
#container{
height:700px !important;
 border:1px solid red;
}
#content{
 height:100%!important;
 border:1px solid green;
}
</style>
<div id="container">
   <div id="content">
    //my content 
   </div>

</div>
```

Comment: i have tried this and its working for me ..even your code is also working for me ..in which browser are you checking

Comment: @user1013512 i have edited my solution and its working fine for me plz have a look

Answer (score 0):

just add min-height:inherit to content style

```
#content{
 height:100%!important;
 min-height:inherit;
}
```